# send processes and threads to run in remote windows host over LAN

Tags: windows, cpu, virtualization

Is there anyway to turn a running software into a distributed software using another kernel mode or user mode process ??

> If the question is not clear, what I want to do is , block a running
>   process and send it's PCB,code, memory dump, etc... over the LAN and
>   run it on a remote windows host and get back with the result.

I assume that there is no virtualization software installed ( VMware or HyperV ) and the local and remote OS are running natively.

**Conclusion**: I want to scale out CPU programmatically without using any virtualization software.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is 'very, very, very difficult'.

Comment: It would require massive OS support, including that of all drivers to checkpoint all hardware interactions.  Add another 'very'.

Comment: Actually i know it is, all what i want to do is a POC, I want to know where to start.

Comment: Windows has no built in facility for this. There are a lot of things that cannot transport between computers, like window handles, kernel handles, file locks, cached values of "GetComputerName", process and thread IDs, pending I/O, network connections...

Comment: @RaymondChen - I was trying very hard to not use the 'i' word :)